# How to display the contents of the array and prompt the user to make a selection {C}

Tags: c, arrays, structure, prompt

The main object of the  program is to display the values within the array called "channels" but i can't seem to get anything to show. After the display is shown I need to prompt the user to choose one of the four channels and display the chosen "channel"'s value. This is what i have so far. I also cannot use any loops. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

// I'm using a structure to store all the values within the array

```
typedef struct

{
   char* name;
   double n; //roughness
   double slope;
   double width;
   double depth;

} CHANNEL;


main ()
{

    CHANNEL channels [4] = {
    {"Channel1", 0.035, 0.0001, 10.0, 2.0},
    {"Channel2", 0.020, 0.0002, 8.0, 1.0},
    {"Channel3", 0.015, 0.0010, 20.0, 1.5},
    {"Channel4", 0.030, 0.0007, 24.0, 3.0}
    };
```

//I want to display all the channels and their values right here... i know i have to use printf but would i need to use a pointer?

```
    printf("Please note:\n 0 = Channel 1 \n 1 = Channel 2 \n 2 = Channel 3 \n 3 = Channel 4);
```

//This part is just for the chosen channel

```
    printf(Pick a channel from 0-3\n");
    int c = 0;
    scanf("%i", &c);
    CHANNEL chosen = channels [c];

}
```

Comment: You aren't printing anything, or asking for any user input. Also this code won't even compile. What have you actually tried doing?

Comment: Why can't you use a loop? It seems the natural way to do so.

Comment: The `name` member of your struct, is only a single `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make the changes that Daniel Litvak suggests. Then, to get information from the user, you should do something like:

```
int main(void) {

    // ...
    printf("Pick a channel from 0-3\n");
    int c = 0;
    scanf("%i ", &c);

    CHANNEL chosen = channels[c];

    printf ("The channel chosen is %s, n = %f, slope = %f and the depth = %f", chosen.name, chosen.n, chosen.slope, chosen.depth);
}
```

This will prompt the user for an index denoting the channel's index in the array. You can also print out all of the channel choices first, if you wish.

For demonstrative purposes, I left the chosen channel in the variable `chosen` and you can proceed as you want.

**EDIT**: No error checking is done to ensure that `c` is within range. This is to avoid displaying any extra, confusing code.

Comment: how would i print out the values of the channel chosen would it be like:

Comment: printf ("The channel chosen is %s, n = %d, slope = %d and the depth = %d", chosen);

Comment: @AjAlmero : I have updated my answer. Also, please note that printing a `double` is done with `%f`.

Comment: Say  i wanted to pass the values of the chosen into another function so i can use them for a calculation. I have trouble with how to pass an array from on function to another and how to call on those values could u show me how to that? Just for an example just add the n, slope, width and depth values so i can see how to do it. btw thanks for all your help so far

Comment: To do that, you'd have a function like `CHANNEL do_some_calcs(CHANNEL channels[])` @AjAlmero

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be that you have a string in a place of a char, a simple solution would be to change the struct to:

```
typedef struct{
char* name;
double n;
double slope;
double depth;
} CHANNEL;
```